# How to check value of radio button before click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have two check boxes on a page, with one checked by default. I want to use jQuery to trigger a custom event when either of the check boxes is clicked. However, the problem is I want to get the checked value *before* the click event, but I keep getting `checked` as `true`.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="clearfix controls">
    <label class="radio inline" for="yes">
        <input type="radio" name="recycle" value="1" id="yes" data-price-increase="29">
        Yes
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline" for="no">
        <input type="radio" name="recycle" value="0" id="no" checked="checked" data-price-decrease="29">
        No
    </label>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```
$('[data-price-increase]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').trigger('price.increase', [ $(this).data('price-increase') ]);
});
$('[data-price-decrease]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').trigger('price.decrease', [ $(this).data('price-decrease') ]);
});
```

But the click handlers get fired multiple times if I continually click a radio button, even if it’s already checked.

The radio buttons add or remove an additional charge respectively, so continually clicking the “Yes” radio button continually adds the charge to the price, which is undesired. If “Yes” is already checked then I don’t want the value adding again.

Comment: How about adding a class (added or something like that) and check for the presence of this class before adding the charge?

Answer (score 3):

I think you look for change event:

```
$('[data-price-increase]').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log('changed');
    $('body').trigger('price.increase', [ $(this).data('price-increase') ]);
});
$('[data-price-decrease]').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log('changed');
    $('body').trigger('price.decrease', [ $(this).data('price-decrease') ]);
});
```

So action is only triggered in case check is changed, not on each click.

Answer (score -2):

ask the target if it´s checked

```
$('[data-price-increase]').on('click', function(e) {
   if(!jQuery(event.target).is(":checked"))
       $('body').trigger('price.increase', [ $(this).data('price-increase') ]);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The checked property has already been set by the time the event handler is called.